# One column into two

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that is one column, and I need to split it into two. I have tried the [`column`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) command and it doesn't seem to work:

```
123-zyx
234-yxw
345-xwv
456-wvu
567-vut
678-uts
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the result should be

Comment: the data on the left of the "-" needs to be one column and the data on the right of the "-" needs to be a column. they are one column right now, so they would become two columns.

Comment: `sed -e 's/-/ /g' <file`

Comment: but when I try and cut one column out of that file, it doesnt do it.

Comment: I did that, then executed:  "cut -f1 -d, file" and it cuts both of them

Comment: To make that file appear as two columns to `cut`, use the option `-d-`.  In this way, ` cut -f1 -d- file` would print the first column and `cut -f2 -d- file` would print the second.

Comment: They are two columns, as long as you consider `-` and not `' '` the column separator.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use `tr` utility:

```
tr '-' $' ' < filename
```

Output:

```
123 zyx
234 yxw
345 xwv
456 wvu
567 vut
678 uts
```

You can `sed` like this:

```
sed 's/-/ /g' < filename
```

Output:

```
123 zyx
234 yxw
345 xwv
456 wvu
567 vut
678 uts
```

Comment: Someone down voted. It would be great if you tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-s` option:

```
column -s- -t file
```

Comment: when i try and cut the first column out after doing what you're suggesting, it cuts both: cut -f1 -d file

Comment: You need `cut -f1 -d' '`

Answer (score 1):

If the sample input data shown is located in a file named *`./in`* then...

```
<in >out tr -- - \\t
```

...would get you two *<tab>* separated columns in a file named *`./out`*.

Depending on your `tr`, though, you might need to use a literal *<tab>* character in place of the last two characters. In fact, you should feel free to substitute those last two for any other delimiter you might want instead.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"} ; { print $1,$2 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bash only:

```
# VERSION 1

while IFS=$'-' read -a line
do
    printf '%s %s\n' ${line[@]}
done < infile > outfile
```

or ...

```
# VERSION 2

main(){ 
  local IFS=$'-\n'
  local a=( $(<infile) )
  printf '%s %s\n' ${a[@]} > outfile
}

main
```

or ...

```
# VERSION 3

while IFS= read -r line
do
  printf '%s\n' "${line/-/ }"
done < infile > outfile
```

But beware: see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234142/48896) if you are thinking of applying this to large files.

---

For fun, some benchmarks on a moderately sized file.  The results follow; 'tr' is clearly the best choice, followed by sed and then awk.  The best Bash is Version 2 (625 times slower than tr and memory usage 82 times higher). By comparison sed is 7.5 times slower and awk is 9 times slower than tr.

```
$ stat -c %s bigdata.txt && wc -l bigdata.txt
1439952
179994 bigdata.txt

# tr '-' $' ' < "$1" > tr.txt

CPU TIME AND RESOURCE USAGE OF './tr bigdata.txt'
VALUES ARE THE AVERAGE OF ( 10 ) TRIALS

CPU, sec :    0.02
CPU, pct :   97.10
RAM, kb  : 1390.00

# sed 's/-/ /g' < "$1" > sed.txt

CPU TIME AND RESOURCE USAGE OF './sed bigdata.txt'
VALUES ARE THE AVERAGE OF ( 10 ) TRIALS

CPU, sec :    0.15
CPU, pct :   98.90
RAM, kb  : 1386.80

# awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"} ; { print $1,$2 }' "$1" > awk.txt

CPU TIME AND RESOURCE USAGE OF './awk bigdata.txt'
VALUES ARE THE AVERAGE OF ( 10 ) TRIALS

CPU, sec :    0.18
CPU, pct :   98.80
RAM, kb  : 1402.00

# BASH: VERSION 1

CPU TIME AND RESOURCE USAGE OF './bash_1 bigdata.txt'
VALUES ARE THE AVERAGE OF ( 10 ) TRIALS

CPU, sec :   16.35
CPU, pct :   99.00
RAM, kb  : 1486.40

# BASH: VERSION 2

CPU TIME AND RESOURCE USAGE OF './bash_2 bigdata.txt'
VALUES ARE THE AVERAGE OF ( 10 ) TRIALS

CPU, sec :   12.51
CPU, pct :   99.40
RAM, kb  : 114002.40

# BASH: VERSION 3

CPU TIME AND RESOURCE USAGE OF './bash_3 bigdata.txt'
VALUES ARE THE AVERAGE OF ( 10 ) TRIALS

CPU, sec :   15.45
CPU, pct :   99.00
RAM, kb  : 1484.00
```